# Android NDK / Exceptions?

Tags: android, c++, exception, stl, android-ndk

I read that only the GNU implementation of the STL supports the C++ exceptions. I'm not sure about what it means exactly.

If I'm not using this implementation, does it mean that :

- The STL does not throw exceptions, but I'm still able to use my own exceptions wherever I want to.
- Or that all the exceptions are disabled, in every piece of code, like they were not a C++ feature ?

Comment: are you using some other STL implementation that isn't the one that comes with the NDK?

Comment: I would like to use gnustl since it supports exceptions, but for some licence reasons I may or may not be allowed to use it. If i'm not then I would use stlport or any other implementation provided with the NDK.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html) page:

> C++ Exceptions
>
> In all versions of the NDK later than NDKr5, the NDK toolchain allows you to use C++ runtimes that support exception handling. However, to ensure compatibility with earlier releases, it compiles all C++ sources with -fno-exceptions support by default. You can enable C++ exceptions either for your entire app, or for individual modules.
>
> To enable exception-handling support for your entire app, add the following line to your Application.mk file. To enable exception-handling support for individual modules', add the following line to their respective Android.mk files.

So, the NDK *can* support STL with exceptions, but it is off by default. [This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html) page details what happens when you use `-fno-exceptions` with GNU compilers (and the NDK compiler is gcc based). Since this STL is implemented all in headers, its usage of exceptions depends on whether the code that includes it (eg. your code) is compiled with or without exceptions. If you use exceptions in your code, and compile with `-fexceptions`, then you can use exceptions as normal in your own code, as well as using exceptions in the STL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that means that if i want to use exceptions in my code (not necessaril based on STL), i also have to use a STL implementation that uses exceptions, because enabling exceptions with a STL that do not support them would be a problem, right ?

Comment: @Virus721: No, not quite. You must *just* take care to *never* unwind into a function compiled without exception-support, or not offering appropriate guarantees when compiled that way. But that point stands for *all code*, not just the standard library.

Comment: The STL on Android does support exceptions, if the module you use it in is compiled with `-fexceptions` as described in the documentation.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm confused. Let's say i'm using a STL implementation that can NOT support exceptions. In this case, can I enable exceptions for my user code, or do i really require an exception compatible STL implementation to use exceptions in my user code ?

Comment: Well, there are two reasons why throwing exceptions through some code could be broken: 1. Because the code was compiled without exception-support, and thus the neccessary unwind-information does not exist. 2. Because the code is simply not exception-safe, which compiling with exception-support cannot heal. Nothing stops you from using exceptions in some part of your code, even if other parts, for either reason, don't support them: It's your responsibility never to expose the code without exception-support to any exceptions though.

Comment: In fact, if you define `APP_STL :=c++_static` with `APP_CFLAGS:=-fexceptions` using latest NDK ($NDK_HOME/sourc.properties says Pkg.Revision=16.1.4479499), your code just won't compile - it complains about absent `logic_error::logic_error(const char*)` from `std::logic_error` which is used in `__throw_logic_error` if `_LIBCPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS` isn't defined (header `stdexcept`).